# How do I search and select names that start with certain letters?

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Email
FROM PATIENT
WHERE [LastName] LIKE 'K%' OR 'Ma%' AND [FirstName] LIKE 'K%' OR 'Ma%';
```

I need to display patients' first name, last name, and email whose last or first name starts with 'K' or 'Ma.'

This is my code and I am confused because MS Access does not recognize my SQL code. I tried to do it in this way as well but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Email
FROM PATIENT
WHERE [LastName] LIKE 'K%' AND 'Ma%' OR [FirstName] LIKE 'K%' AND 'Ma%';
```

How can I make my code be recognized by Access and print the correct results?

Comment: @ADyson I got unexpected results. It shows not only patients whose name starts with 'K' or 'Ma' but also patients whose name starts with other letters

Answer (score 3):

You can't skip mentioning the column name for each comparison you want to make. Otherwise something like  `[LastName] LIKE 'K%' OR 'Ma%'` evaluates as `[LastName] LIKE 'K%' OR true` - because you're not comparing `Ma%` to anything else, so it's simply true on its own. And of course if you have `true` on either side of an `OR` then the whole clause ends up evaluating as `true`.

Also you've made a mess of the ANDs and ORs in the second example - e.g. the first name cannot start with `K` *and* start with `Ma`!

Lastly in MS Access the wildcard for LIKE is `*` not `%`.

This should be what you need.

```
WHERE 
  [LastName] LIKE 'K*' 
  OR [LastName] LIKE 'Ma*' 
  OR [FirstName] LIKE 'K*' 
  OR [FirstName] LIKE'Ma*';
```

Documentation: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/like-operator-b2f7ef03-9085-4ffb-9829-eef18358e931

Comment: I see what you are saying. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It depends when you only want persons that start with `K` and `Ma` in the first **and** last name, you could use

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Email
FROM PATIENT
WHERE ([LastName] LIKE 'K*' OR [LastName] LIKE 'Ma*') 
  AND ([FirstName] LIKE 'K*' OR [FirstName] LIKE 'Ma*');
```

If you don't mind where the letter occurs, you better use this:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Email
FROM PATIENT
WHERE [LastName] LIKE 'K*' OR [LastName] LIKE 'Ma*' 
   OR [FirstName] LIKE 'K*' OR [FirstName] LIKE 'Ma*';
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help! I actually tried both ways but for some reason, it doesn't seem to work. It only shows blank results. I think MS Access does not recognize the SQL code. Can you help me to figure out what's the problem that I'm missing? This is my database: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z8CSK1IHBKVJN_Vc7oU_ipCbmkh9JGCz/view?usp=sharing

Comment: that is because the wilddcard of MSACCESS is * not % see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-wildcards-in-queries-and-parameters-in-access-ec057a45-78b1-4d16-8c20-242cde582e0b i changed the answer

Comment: Oh I see so it was * not % thanks

Comment: no see my parenthesis for the query AND is always for 'OR